# PHP not parsing

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have changed some settings(In the hope webdav would work) and updated php from 5.3 to 5.4.23. Now PHP isn't parsing anymore. Does someone know how to fix it? I'm really desperate
CentOS Linux 5.10
Apache 2.2.3
html is working fine

My httpd.conf file
http://pastebin.com/jj4uvhKy

My php.conf file
http://pastebin.com/7agK5uSg

Apache error logs

```
    [Sun Dec 29 18:40:07 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:33 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:35 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:35 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:35 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:35 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:36 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 50 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:36 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Sun Dec 29 18:42:36 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 29 18:45:26 2013] [error] [client 162.243.193.142] File does not exist: /var/www/html/robots.txt
```

httpd -S

```
    VirtualHost configuration:
    94.46.245.2:80         is a NameVirtualHost
             default server domain1.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1018)
             port 80 namevhost domain1.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1018)
                     alias www.domain1.net
                     alias webmail.domain1.net
                     alias admin.domain1.net
             port 80 namevhost domain2.eu (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1076)
                     alias www.domain2.eu
                     alias webmail.domain2.eu
                     alias admin.domain2.eu
             port 80 namevhost domain3.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1134)
                     alias www.domain3.com
                     alias webmail.domain3.com
                     alias admin.domain3.com
             port 80 namevhost domain4.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1192)
                     alias www.domain4.org
                     alias webmail.domain4.org
                     alias admin.domain4.org
             port 80 namevhost domain5.be (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1250)
                     alias www.domain5.be
                     alias webmail.domain5.be
                     alias admin.domain5.be
             port 80 namevhost domain6.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1305)
                     alias www.domain6.net
                     alias webmail.domain6.net
                     alias admin.domain6.net
             port 80 namevhost testtest.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1365)
                     alias www.testtest.com
                     alias webmail.testtest.com
                     alias admin.testtest.com
             port 80 namevhost domain7.net (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1422)
                     alias www.domain7.net
                     alias webmail.domain7.net
                     alias admin.domain7.net
             port 80 namevhost domain8.be (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1480)
                     alias www.domain8.be
                     alias webmail.domain8.be
                     alias admin.domain8.be
             port 80 namevhost domain9.be (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1538)
                     alias www.domain9.be
                     alias webmail.domain9.be
                     alias admin.domain9.be
             port 80 namevhost domain10.eu (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1595)
                     alias www.domain10.eu
                     alias webmail.domain10.eu
                     alias admin.domain10.eu
    94.46.245.2:443        is a NameVirtualHost
             default server domain5.be (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1652)
             port 443 namevhost domain5.be (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1652)
                     alias www.domain5.be
                     alias webmail.domain5.be
                     alias admin.domain5.be
    wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
    _default_:443          server.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
    Syntax OK
```

I know it's not te first thread about this but I can't resolve the problem. I tried every solution I could find.

Comment: It seems you are attempting to load two instances of php. I would recommend to look at httpd.conf closely - maybe make a 'light' version just to get things working, them slowly add more stuff.

Comment: I resolved that problem and changed the first post. But php is still not parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code.

Check out which backward incompatible changes are affecting you..

[Taken from PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php)

Plus, you'll want to review specific PHP changes from 5.3 to 5.4

[PHP Migration notes from 5.3 to 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php)